# On-Demand Query with siddhi fails

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, event-stream-processing

I'm using the wso2 stream integrator in order to run my siddhi application.
The operating environment is windows 10 pro.
I'd like to ask you for your help about way of using Siddhi's REST API.

1. Open a command prompt as the administrator and go to \wso2si-1.1.0\bin. Then, execute the command `server.bat --run`.
2. Deploy any siddhi files in wso2si-1.1.0\wso2\server\deployment\siddhi-files, and it's working correctly.
3. Open a new command prompt and execute the command `curl -X GET "http://localhost:9090/siddhi-apps" -H "accept: application/json" -u "admin:admin" -k`.
4. The command succeeds and a list of applications is displayed.
5. Next, I defined the `ABC` as named-window on `FlowApp` and executed the command `curl -X POST "https://localhost:9443/query" -H "content-type: application/json" -u "admin:admin" -d "{"appName" : "FlowApp", "query" : "from ABC select *" }" -k`
6. The above query fails and "Problem accessing: /query. Reason: Not Found" is displayed on the command prompt.

Why can't I find "/query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default query API is available in a different port. Try port number 7443

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:7443/query" -H "content-type: application/json" -u "admin:admin" -d "{"appName" : "FlowApp", "query" : "from ABC select *" }" -k
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it on port number 7443 but it didn't work.

Comment: in the delpyment.yaml, check the ports under `siddhi.stores.query.api` config. The default is 7443, if you have changed it may have also